# Scrolling / dragging is stopping counter in Android 2.2

Tags: android, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using JQM and Phonegap for my Android App. I am showing a counter on a page. But when I start scrolling/dragging on that page, the counter pauses at that time and again gets resume and shows incremented value when I lift up my thumb.

As per docs from jQueryMobile

scrollstart: Triggers when a scroll begins. Note that iOS devices freeze DOM manipulation during scroll, queuing them to apply when the scroll finishes. We're currently investigating ways to allow DOM manipulations to apply before a scroll starts.

But it seems also happening with Android 2.2

How can I keep showing clock running while user scroll or drag on screen.

Comment: Android 2.2 don't update DOM while scrolling or swiping on the screen. This is just like 'Note that iOS devices freeze DOM manipulation during scroll'.